# Dell mouse not working properly

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse

I have a Dell mouse (can't find a model number on it so I attached a picture) that doesn't work very well.  Using it with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it works perfectly with no problems, but when I use it with Windows 10 its extremely jittery and sometimes stops working completely until I unplug it and plug it back in.  I'm pretty sure this is a driver issue, but I'm running all the latest drivers.  Please help.[image]

Answer (score -1):

"All the latest drivers" OK, but that looks pretty old to me! How about using older drivers? The newest ones might not support old mice(again, at least it looks old to me). And if it's supported by the newest drivers, look, again, at your drivers: maybe it's the wrong driver/s(i don't think drivers for gaming mice with a built-in keyboard work very well for a office mouse).